# If you ask: Where do you live? Versus: Do you live at so & so and vice versa. Is one is called general and the other is called particular?

Tags: single-word-requests

If you ask someone "Where do you live?" versus "Do you live at so & so", is a question like the first called *general* and the second called *particular*?

Another example is "What do you think about sex?" versus "Do you think so & so about sex?"

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question. Are you asking what the difference is between "in general" and "in particular" and what kinds of sentences those phrases would apply to?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make conversation with someone, it is often recommended to avoid asking *yes/no* questions, and instead ask *open-ended* questions (that is, ones that invite a full sentence (or more!) as a reply).

Your examples of "Where do you live?" and "What do you think about sex?" are examples of open-ended questions, whereas "Do you live at (X)?" and "Do you think (X) about sex?" are yes/no questions.